# Wordpress API Setting : the title of the section rendered not showing

Tags: settings-api

Please see the below-mentioned code →

```
    function klogeto_initialize_theme_options() {
    // Let's introduce a section for the header options
    add_settings_section(
        'header_section',                           // The ID to use for this section in attribute tags
        'Header Options',                           // The title of the section rendered to the screen
        'klogeto_logo_display',                     // The function used to render the options for this section
        'klogeto-theme-header-options'              // The ID of the page on which this section is rendered
    );

    add_settings_field(
    'display_logo',                              // The ID (or the name) of the field
    'Upload a logo',                             // The text used to label the field
    'klogeto_logo_display_field',                // The callback function used to render the field
    'klogeto-theme-header-logo-options',         // The page on which we'll be rendering this field
    'header_section'                             // The section to which we're adding the setting
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'klogeto_initialize_theme_options' );
```

But the problem is that the text **Header Options** is not displaying in the theme options panel.

> 'Header Options',                         // The title of the section rendered to the
>   screen

what mistake I am doing? Looks like some silly mistake that I cant diagnose.

I forget to mentioned that I have also written this line of code →

```
    register_setting(
    'header_section',                   // The name of the group of settings
    'header_options',                   // The name of the actual option (or setting)
    'klogeto_sanitize_header_options'       // The callback to footer sanitization option
);
```

Comment: Hi, If you are trying to add a theme option page, i would suggest you use the `add_theme_page()` instead. It's been introduced just for this purpose.

Comment: for now, I am trying to register sections and fields, but that is not populating as I have mentioned above in the question sir. Actually, I was trying to learn through this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-wordpress-settings-api-part-2-sections-fields-and-settings--wp-24619)

Comment: These things add_settings_section or dd_settings_field are obsolete or not in use?

Comment: I don't see any error in your code, however it would be nice to see the entire code you are using to add the option page.

Comment: I have posted the whole code now.

Comment: @Jack Johansson Please help me, sir, as I am quiet stressed.

Comment: Sure. I'm trying your code in my localhost and it displays nothing. Please give me a few minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59900/discussion-between-the-wp-novice-and-jack-johansson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided lacks a lot of sections and it outputs nothing when i use it on my localhost. I've written and tested a full class for you that does what you are looking for.

```
// Start Class
if ( ! class_exists( 'my_Theme_Options' ) ) {
    class my_Theme_Options {
        public function __construct() {
            // We only need to register the admin panel on the back-end
            if ( is_admin() ) {
                add_action( 'admin_menu', array( 'my_Theme_Options', 'my_add_admin_menu' ) );
                add_action( 'admin_init', array( 'my_Theme_Options', 'my_register_settings' ) );
            }
        }
        // Returns all theme options 
        public static function get_my_theme_options() {
            return get_option( 'my_theme_options' );
        }
        // Returns single theme option
        public static function my_get_theme_option_value( $id ) {
            $options = self::get_my_theme_options();
            if ( isset( $options[$id] ) ) {
                return $options[$id];
            }
        }
        // Add sub menu page
        public static function my_add_admin_menu() {
            add_options_page(
                esc_html__( 'my Options', 'text-domain' ),
                esc_html__( 'my Options', 'text-domain' ),
                'manage_options',
                'my-theme-settings',
                array( 'my_Theme_Options', 'my_create_admin_page' )
            );
        }
        // Register a setting and its sanitization callback.
        public static function my_register_settings() {
            register_setting( 'my_theme_options', 'my_theme_options', array( 'my_Theme_Options', 'my_sanitize' ) );
        }
        // Sanitization callback
        public static function my_sanitize( $options ) {
            // If we have options lets sanitize them
            if ( $options ) {
                // Input
                if ( ! empty( $options['sample_input'] ) ) {
                    $options['sample_input'] = sanitize_text_field( $options['sample_input'] );
                } else {
                    unset( $options['sample_input'] ); // Remove from options if empty
                }
            }
            // Return sanitized options
            return $options;
        }
        // Now we output our form to save and view our options
        public static function my_create_admin_page() { ?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <h1><?php esc_html_e( 'Theme Options', 'text-domain' ); // The heading for Option page ?></h1>
                <?php settings_errors(); // Output any error if exists ?>
                <form method="post" action="options.php">
                    <?php settings_fields( 'my_theme_options' ); ?>
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Heading', 'text-domain' ); ?>
                    <table class="form-table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Sample Input', 'text-domain' ); ?>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <?php $value = self::my_get_theme_option_value( 'sample_input' ); // We retrieve and output this option in the input area ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="my_theme_options[sample_input]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <?php submit_button(); // Let's have a button to save the form, shall we? ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }
}
new my_Theme_Options();
// Helper function to use in theme to return a theme option value
function my_get_theme_option( $id = '' ) {
    return my_Theme_Options::my_get_theme_option_value( $id );
}
```

I used a simple text input as an example, but you can use checkbox, radio buttons, anything you want.

I've added explanation to everywhere i could, however if you have any questions about what does a part of the code do, make sure you let me know about it.